# Dynamics 365 (CRM) Version 9.1 online C# code Error: Entity Id must be the same as the value set in property bag

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

When cloning/copying child records, I use a foreach loop and then create a record with all its attributes. I wrote similar code in another project and worked fine for me.

There are multiple articles/questions based on the same Error. Now my issue is how should I create child records with all its attributes.

```
foreach (var packingList in oPEntityCollection.Entities)
{                                        
    packingList.Attributes.Remove("statuscode");
    packingList.Attributes.Remove("statecode"); 
    packingList.Id=Guid.Empty; 
    orgService.Create(packingList);
}
```

Another strange issue

> An entry with the same key already exists

Code:

```
Entity parentEntity = orgService.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId, new ColumnSet(true));    
parentEntity.Id = Guid.empty;
orgService.Create(parentEntity);
```

Even if I create a new object and copy `parentEntity` just like below I get this error.

```
Entity costcalEntity = new Entity();

costcalEntity = parentEntity;
costcalEntity.Id = Guid.Empty;
orgService.Create(costcalEntity);
```

So I end up creating a record with primary name and once the record is created, I update the same record with old record attributes.

```
Entity costcalEntity = new Entity();
costcalEntity.LogicalName = parentEntity.LogicalName;
costcalEntity["name"] = parentQuotationEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
costcalEntity.Id = Guid.Empty;
Guid newGuid = orgService.Create(costcalEntity);
if (newGuid != Guid.Empty)
{
    costcalEntity = parentEntity;
    costcalEntity.Id = newGuid;
    orgService.Update(costcalEntity);
}
```

and this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you have the same issue, with it's root cause being the Id stored in the attribute collection of the entity.  If you look at the early bound generation, you can access the Id by the entity.Id property, as well as the attribute collection as shown in the definition for the id in the primary id:

```
public System.Nullable<System.Guid> AccountId
{
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
    get
    {
        return this.GetAttributeValue<System.Nullable<System.Guid>>("accountid");
    }
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
    set
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanging("AccountId");
        this.SetAttributeValue("accountid", value);
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            base.Id = value.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            base.Id = System.Guid.Empty;
        }
        this.OnPropertyChanged("AccountId");
    }
}
```

So when you are retrieving an existing entity, both the Property Id, which you have handled, as well as the attribute collection, which you haven't handled, have been populated by the CRM SDK.  So in order to be able to duplicate it, you'll need to clear the id in both places.

Comment: well I did cleared Id in both places. As mentioned I had almost same code for another project and worked fine. But I found out that rather than assigning retrieved Entity directly to new Entity object rather just add it's attribute and then yes do not forget to remove primary Id as it will be created by CRM.

Comment: In your examples you don't show yourself clearing the id in the Attributes collection.

Comment: Yes I did not mentioned in my first piece of code. Just updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it

```
 foreach (Entity packingList in oPEntityCollection.Entities)
                {
                    Entity newpackingList = new Entity()
                    {
                        LogicalName = packingList.LogicalName,
                    };
                    newpackingList.Attributes.AddRange(packingList.Attributes);                        
                    newpackingList.Attributes.Remove("primaryGuid");                       
                    Guid newOpGuid = orgService.Create(newpackingList);    
                    tracingService.Trace($"OP record created sucessfully with guid {newOpGuid}");

                    }
```

**So the Trick, issue was rather I was trying to assign `packingList` directly to `newpackingList`. This caused to assign `packingList` metadata attributes as well such. This was not acceptable with crm**

But rather I should add it's attribute. This worked and created all child records.

Same worked for parent record as well

```
Entity parentEntity = orgService.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId, new ColumnSet(true)); 

   Entity newParentEntity = new Entity()
                        {
                            LogicalName = parentEntity.LogicalName,
                        };
newParentEntity.Attributes.AddRange(parentEntity.Attributes); 
 newParentEntity.Attributes.Remove("primaryGuid");
orgService.Create(newParentEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "How do I duplicate an Entity retrieved from CRM?", your answer can be simplified.

```cs
var entity = orgService.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId, new ColumnSet(true)); 
entity.Id = Guid.Empty;
entity.Attributes.Remove("primaryGuid");
orgService.Create(entity);
```

Comment: those were my first four line of codes for copying record, As mentioned same code worked with another env but for the one I am writing code gave me,**An entry with the same key already exists** and Hence I tried few other ways such as creating entity just with primary name and then updating this record with parent record object.
Long story short this does not work in current scenario, However code has no issues running another instance.

Comment: @AnkUser I guess I'm confused about the "first four lines of codes for copying records"  Are you talking about your answer?  Because no where in the question do you remove the Id from the Attributes collection, just the state/status.

Comment: sorry for confusion, I meant when I started writing plugin, above four lines were my starting point and I hoped this would solve the purpose but it did not. As stated in my answer and my question just using same entity object and removing it's Id returned  **An entry with the same key already exists**

Answer (score 0):

I've used these two functions for a while now seems to do the job:

Call in your case would look like this :

```
var newParentEntity = CloneRecord(parentEntity, orgService, null);

internal Entity CloneRecord(Entity entity, IOrganizationService service, ITracingService trace)
{
    Entity newEntity = new Entity(entity.LogicalName);
    List<string> atts =  getEntityAttributesToClone(entity.LogicalName, service, ref var PrimaryIdAttribute, ref var PrimaryNameAttribute);

    foreach (string att in atts)
    {
        if (entity.Attributes.Contains(att) && att != "statuscode" && att != "statecode")
            newEntity.Attributes.Add(att, entity.Attributes[att]);
    }           
    return newEntity;
}

internal List<string> getEntityAttributesToClone(string entityName, IOrganizationService service,
        ref string PrimaryIdAttribute, ref string PrimaryNameAttribute)
{
    List<string> atts = new List<string>();
    RetrieveEntityRequest req = new RetrieveEntityRequest()
    {
        EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes,
        LogicalName = entityName
    };

    RetrieveEntityResponse res = (RetrieveEntityResponse)service.Execute(req);
    PrimaryIdAttribute = res.EntityMetadata.PrimaryIdAttribute;

    foreach (AttributeMetadata attMetadata in res.EntityMetadata.Attributes)
    {
        if (attMetadata.IsPrimaryName.Value)
            PrimaryNameAttribute = attMetadata.LogicalName;
        if ((attMetadata.IsValidForCreate.Value || attMetadata.IsValidForUpdate.Value)
                && !attMetadata.IsPrimaryId.Value)
            atts.Add(attMetadata.LogicalName);              
    }
    return (atts);
}
```